# Workflow only fires on create regardless of Evaluation Criteria

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow on a picklist that only fires on create regardless of the Evaluation Criteria. I have changed the workflow multiple times to no avail. I have tried "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria" and "created, and every time it's edited" yet it only fires when the record is created. I deleted the workflow and recreated it, but the same outcome persists. I am working on a developer org. Any thoughts?

[image: Simple Workflow]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what to make of it. Try formula instead

```
AND( ISCHANGED(Test__c), ISPICKVAL(Test__c, 'Yes') )
```

and change condition to 'created, and every time it's edited'

Or move it to Process Builder and see if it works there.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, sadly it doesn't work either. I wonder if there is something off with this org. This is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to fire on every update, regardless if there were changes, then definitely use "When created and every time it's edited". If you use the "..and every time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria" it would have be updated at least twice: once to not satisfy the criteria and then back again.

Could there be another automatism "invalidating" the record?

Setup a Debug trace for your user with workflow level on at least info (should be default) and see what's happening in there. You should be able to see the criteria rule and values of the relevant fields.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I tried all suggestions including looking at the debug log but didn't see anything suspicious if I'm reading it right. It is still not working and the odd thing is that I have very complex workflows that work in production.

Comment: Can you see the rule evaluated in the log with the formula resulting in "false"?

Comment: The log is looking good. Like I mentioned, I have complex workflows that work in prod. This one is only evaluating one field and **works well as a field update**. I also requested an email log and the emails are being apparently recorded but not sent. I have come to think that the developer's org does not send emails on edits and only on create, at least that is my situation. If this is true then I am not worried as it should not be a problem in prod. It is however a pain since I cannot test the workflow properly. I'm using a field update action for testing in the meantime, until confirmed.